# admin.firestore is not a function when trying to use google cloud functions with node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

This is the header of the node.js index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();
```

This is the node.js function to listen to firestore changes:

```
exports.myFoo = functions.firestore
  .document('foo/{bar}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    // do stuff
}
```

This is in the package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5-.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1",
    "firestore": "^1.1.6"
  },
```

When I try to do a "firebase deploy" command this is the error I am getting:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
> TypeError: admin.firestore is not a function

## askFirebase

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the latest version of the SDK.  Get it as described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize_functions_sdk) by running `npm install firebase-functions@latest --save` in your project's functions directory.

Comment: I don't think you need firestore in the dependencies? I have a working firestore/firebase-functions snippet, with only two dependencies `"firebase-admin": "^5.4.1"` and `"firebase-functions": "^0.7.0"`

Comment: @BobSnyder I ran both `npm install firebase-functions@latest --save` and `npm install -g firebase-tools` then tried a  `firebase deploy` again but the same error message is still coming up. I have firebase version 3.13.1 and npm version 3.10.10.

Comment: @DauleDK I removed firestore from the dependencies and a deploy is still throwing the same error message.

Comment: maybe you can try to delete node_modules and npm lock file, and install again?

Comment: @DauleDK at this point I am just going to try to reinstall everything. I hate firebase.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a hyphen in this line? `"firebase-admin": "^5-.4.2",`

Comment: @AjahnCharles good catch there, I wonder if that was part of my problem. I have it working now and that hyphen after the 5 is not there anymore, now it has `"firebase-admin": "^5.4.2",`.

Comment: @AjahnCharles looking back at my edits to this post I originally had `"firebase-admin": "^5.4.2",` when the problem first started. At some point during the process of hunting down a solution I noticed the change to the added hyphen in the version number and updated the post. That would mean it even though it could have been a problem, it wasn't "the" problem for this error. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error and brute-force a solution.  I don't know much about `npm` and can't offer a complete explanation of why this solution worked.

My original `package.json` contained:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1",
    ...
  },
```

As [recommended in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize_functions_sdk), I ran these two commands in the functions folder:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
```

I also tried:

```
npm install --save firebase-admin
npm upgrade
```

I repeatedly received these error messages:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase-admin@4.2.1
npm WARN firebase-functions@0.7.1 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.4.2 but none was installed.
```

I figured `firebase-admin` needed to be updated but couldn't make it happen.  So I edited the dependencies file to delete this line:

```
"firebase-admin": "^4.2.1"
```

then ran `npm install --save firebase-admin` again.  With that, the `package.json` contained version `"firebase-admin": "^5.4.2"` and `var db = admin.firestore();` compiled without error.

Comment: looks like your answer helped be again [here on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822579/upgrading-to-cloud-functions-v1-0-and-i-broke-everything). Thanks. Maybe future me will remember this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const getReceiverDataPromise = admin.firestore().doc('users/' + receiverUID).get();
const getSenderDataPromise = admin.firestore().doc('users/' + senderUID).get();

return Promise.all([getReceiverDataPromise, getSenderDataPromise]).then(results => {

        const receiver = results[0].data();
        console.log("receiver: ", receiver);

        const sender = results[1].data();
        console.log("sender: ", sender);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`functions.firestore` is supposed to be `functions.firestore()`

Answer (score -2):

To solve in your file.js (async method) :

```
const getFirestore = () => admin.firestore()
```

exemple :

```
 getFirestore()
  .collection(`mailchimp-users`)
  .doc(uid)
    .set(profile)
      .then(() => res.redirect(MAILCHIMP_AUTH_SUCCESS_URL))
      .catch((error) => res.json({error}))
```