# Upgrading to Cloud Functions v1.0 and I broke everything

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Trying to follow the instructions on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore) and I can't figure out how to simply get to the data in the DocumentSnapshot.

They do not really explain updating onCreate, except to say it is the same as onDelete, and I can't get that to work.

```
 exports.mFoo = functions.firestore
    .document('foos/{key}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => { 

      const bar = snap.data(); // <-- DOESN'T WORK
      console.log(bar); // <-- DOESN'T WORK

    return Promise;
});
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: snap.data is not a function at
>   exports.mFoo.functions.firestore.document.onCreate

I'm sure it's super simple but I don't really understand this stuff and I have tried tons of combinations of stuff and nothing works.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the latest version of firebase-functions and firebase-admin?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman thanks, I had installed but I had to reinstall. Details in answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I ran into the same problem that I have [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679472/admin-firestore-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-use-google-cloud-functions-with).

Before doing any of these types of updates:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@5.11.0 --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

First I have to open my package.json file and delete any dependencies that are going to be updated.

These were what I found there:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1"
  },
```

After leaving the dependencies empty and rerunning those commands to install, these showed up:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

Apparently installs and upgrades won't fix these dependencies but they will add them if they aren't there. Maybe it is possible to fix it by typing those in but I wouldn't have had a clue what version numbers to put there.

Now the (modified) code works:

```
 exports.mFoo = functions.firestore
    .document('foos/{key}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => { 

      const bar = snap.data(); // now this works
      console.log(bar.baz); // <-- before I wasn't referring to anything in the snapshot

    return Promise; // I. Promised. Nothing.
});
```

Thanks [@Todd Kerpelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2005061/todd-kerpelman) for pointing me in the right direction and [@Bob Snyder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4815718/bob-snyder) because the same answer from the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679472/admin-firestore-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-use-google-cloud-functions-with) worked for me here also.