# admin.firestore(...).document is not a function at exports

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a cloud function that is triggered by a firebase realtime database change and updates FireStore. However, although the function triggers, the function cannot access the Firestore.

```js
exports.reveal = functions.database.ref('/reveals/{postIDthatWasRevealed}/revealed').onUpdate((change, context) => {
const revealedValue = change.after.val()

if (revealedValue === true) {
   var updates = {}
   const postID = context.params.postIDthatWasRevealed
   return admin.firestore().document('/posters/' + postID).get().then(querySnapshot => {
```

At this point, the console log states `TypeError:admin.firestore(...).document is not a function at..` I have already tried this answer :[Tried Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679472/admin-firestore-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-use-google-cloud-functions-with) But the problem continues. Does this have to do with the fact that I am accessing firestore inside of firebase cloud function? Are my cloud functions not properly updated?

Edit (Includes Initialization code)

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

In addition, I have tried to debug the function by changing it to :

```js
if (revealedValue === true) {
   var updates = {}
   const postID = context.params.postIDthatWasRevealed

   return admin.firestore()
```

Now, when I trigger the function, I get `Function execution took 811 ms, finished with status: 'ok'` Thus, it seems as if the firestore function is valid, just that my syntax may be off or I may be forgetting something

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `doc()` function instead of `document()`

Answer (score 8):

`document()` is a property of [`functions.firestore`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

The equivalent for `admin.firestore()` is `collection().doc()`

See [`Firestore: Get Data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) for more info.

```
admin.firestore().collection('posters').doc(postID) ...
```

Comment: That did not fix anything. Error remains. Pretty sure either cloud functions are not installed correctly / updated or that I may be accessing Firestore incorrectly.

Comment: Changing `document()` to `collection().doc()` didn't work?

Comment: No, the error simply changes to firestore(...).collection is not a function at ..

Comment: That suggests that `collection == undefined` where you are attempting to call it. The value returned by `admin.firestore()` isn't quite copacetic. I would recommend splitting up the logic into separate variables (`firestore = admin.firestore()`, `collectionRef = firestore.collection()`, etc) and logging the values of each to find where the chain breaks @RaimKhalil

Comment: how exactly would I log it ?

Comment: [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log). I'd also confirm `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'` and [`admin.initializeApp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk) are hooked up correctly @RaimKhalil

Comment: alright I’ll try that in a little bit and see if that works

Comment: when I add `import * as admin from ('firebase-admin')` I get the error `Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType:module' I edited the answer to include everything before the function.

Comment: The problem was I was using .document() instead of .doc()