# the first try to firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to make my first firebase cloud function.
I want to add the value of name field -which is in 'amr' document -inside ahmed document with the field name newName . I made this function but each time it gives an error or don't show anything
what is the problem in my function

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin=require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();
    exports.myfunc=functions.firestore.document('Users/amr').onWrite((change,context)=>{

    const name=change.data().name;         
    return admin.firestore().document('Users/ahmed').add({newName:name});
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
const name=change.data().name;
```

into this:

```
const name=change.after.data().name;
```

to be able to retrieve the data after the write

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore

Comment: error has appeared>>TypeError: admin.firestore(...).document is not a function
    at exports.myfunc.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:11:34)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236987/admin-firestore-document-is-not-a-function-at-exports

Answer (score 0):

also change

```
    return admin.firestore().document('Users/ahmed').add({newName:name});
```

to

```
    return admin.firestore().doc('Users/ahmed').add({newName:name});
```

Comment: Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions and then function execution error

Comment: Firebase will not allow you to make requests to an external server if you've not set a billing method
Normally this appears just as a warning in the cli unless you try to make a request
What are you trying to achive?

Comment: i just want to train on firebase cloud functions and try my first and you see that it doesnt work so if you have a simple function to test i will be grateful

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787576/5927361
Everything should work unless you want to send an outbound request, which is probably not the case